# Does curl up imply that something is trying to completely cover something in a curl?

Tags: meaning

"The tentacle curled up on his finger."

Does the above mean that the tentacle almost covered the finger whole?

> to arrange oneself in or as if in a ball or curl

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curl%20up

It doesn't seem to imply that the tentacle is trying to stick onto the finger to almost cover all of it or most of it. How do you convey this?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with covering his finger or not. It probably means that the tentacle (like a cat or a dog) came to rest and shaped itself into a curl on his finger. If you’ve seen a cat or dog curl up, that’s the idea.

Comment: To curl up **on** something is not the same as to curl up **around** something.

Comment: When a person or animal 'curls up', they draw in all their limbs close to the body, but a tentacle is only one limb, so it probably made a single loop round the finger.

Comment: Another problem here is that the sentence doesn't say if the curl is horizontal or vertical. If it was horizontal, then like a cat, the tentacle could curl up into a circle laying flat. If vertical, then it could curl into a circle like a tire. Because the sentence doesn't say *around* we have to conclude that it did make a curl on top of his finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "*to curl*" means to *grow into the shape of a curl*.

To *curl **around*** means that as it curled, it moved around another object, perhaps deliberately. It doesn't necessarily mean to cover it entirely.

When "up" follows a verb, it often means that something has been done to completion (for example, 'finish up', 'wash up', 'blow up' etc). To *curl **up*** means to curl as far as possible*, for example, if a person 'curled up in a ball' they would draw their extremities into their body as tightly as possible.

You could perhaps convey the idea that something was entirely covered by the tentacle by saying it "*wrapped* around". When something is wrapped, it is covered.

Comment: So curl up imply the thing curled up and made a single loop or two while curl up around means the same except it made more curls and what does curl around mean exactly does it mean it made less than two curls??

Comment: @Sayaman - It has nothing to do with the number of curls.  Curled **up** means "curled into a ball".  Curled **around** means, well, **around** something else.  A cat can be curled **up** on top of a bed, but it is not curled **around** anything when it does that.